# Is there a particle that strongly emphasizes the meaning of an adjective or adverb?

Tags: adjective, adverb

In English, one would say "The weather is so *damn* cold!" or "The S-Bahn strikes happen so *frigging* often!"  Is there something similar in German?

I know that, in some cases, you can use an absolute superlative, like *arschkalt*, or just say *sehr kalt*; but that feels a bit tame to me, and doesn't always express the depth of my emotion.

Comment: _saukalt, arschkalt, scheißkalt, verdammt kalt, verflixt kalt, ungeheuer kalt, unglaublich kalt_ … Some of these work with other adjectives, too.

Comment: *Arschkalt* is, quite frankly, the best translation you can give for *damn cold*. Even for people who dislike the cold, *arschkalt* wouldn't start until they're really freezing.

Comment: Interesting side note: "sehr" was once itself a sort of "swear word" working as an intensifier. It meant something like "painfully" and connected the word that should be intensified with physical agony; so "sehr kalt" literally meant "so cold that it hurts". "Sehr" is related to "versehren" (to hurt, to injure). Over the centuries "sehr" lost its connotation and is today a pure intensifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the literal translation:

> verdammt kalt

Or this one is also commonly used:

> hammer-

as intensification or maximization prefix.

---

I've heard *mega* quite often but I wouldn't use it.

> Es tut so mega weh!

sounds for instance teenager-vocabulary.

Comment: also "hammer"... hammerkalt, hammeroft, hammerlangsam...

Comment: It doesn't need to be a prefix either... "Thomas ist hammer der Idiot.". "BMW is hammer das Looserauto." Oh and at least in the east, there's also "übelst"

Comment: @Emanuel Für mich klingen beide deiner Beispielsätze falsch und wüsste ich es nicht besser, würde ich dich als "non-native" abstempeln. Ich überleg grad, ob ich im Bezug zu dieser Frage überhaupt "hammer" verwenden würde. "hammerkalt", "hammerweh"... tut's alles nicht. Ich erachte das Wort hier im Kontext als falsch.

Comment: @Em1... dann ist's 'ne regionale Sache. "Hammer" ist für mich (Berlin) der Intensivierer Nummer 1, weit vor "verdammt" und den ganzen anderen Standards. Here some examples that are probably funny to you: https://www.google.de/search?q=%22hammersch%C3%B6n%22&client=opera&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&gws_rd=ssl&oq=%22hammersch%C3%B6n%22&gs_l=heirloom-serp.3...6712.7334.0.7629.5.5.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-serp..5.0.0.8byl9hvCrms my favorite is "Hammerschön und Hammeraugen."

Comment: @Emanuel Ich bin in Hamburg aufgewachsen und kann dich leider ebenfalls nicht nachvollziehen. Ich sage zwar nie Hammer, kann mir aber nicht vorstellen inwiefern "Hammer das Looserauto" ein gültiger Dialektbestandteil sein kann. Ich könnte mir jedoch einfach "Hammer!" vorstellen. :o)

Comment: @Emanuel Culcha Candela ist eine Berliner Gruppe, oder? "Du bist der Hammer" ist für mich übrigens OK; auch schon vor dem Song. "Das ist ja der Hammer" genau so. Hammerschön und Hammeraugen, wie du schon erraten hast, geht gar nicht. Interessanterweise sind die Absolute Beginner jedoch von Hamburg, und die sangen "Hammerhart".

Comment: @Em1... oh Gott, Culcha Candela. Furchtbar :). Vielleicht ist "Hammer" so ein Nordding. Guter Punkt übrigens mit Absolute Beginner... vielleicht kam das "hammer" ja damals mit Deutschrap auf.

Comment: Abgesehen davon, dass das ganze wohl regional unterschiedlich ist, spielt wohl das Alter des Sprechers eine entscheidende Rolle...

Answer (score 2):

You can use any number of different words: *verdammt*, *verflucht*, or (if you'd rather avoid swearing) you could use *heftig*, *extrem*, *gewaltig*, and to add even more emphasis: *wirklich heftig*, or *wirklich extrem*. More colloquial would be *echt extrem*.

Comment: "so was von kalt"
"einfach nur kalt"
"völlig kalt"
"kalt wie Sau"
"schweinekalt"
...the list goes on. There are few tasks in language that have as many solutions as intensifying. They are also particularly susceptible to rapid change, maybe because the meaning is still intellegible even if you've never heard a particular intensifier.

Answer (score 2):

One other, very commonly used intensifier is ***derbe***, other ones include *voll*/*total* (roughly equivalent to fully or totally in that context) or ***krass***. These are a bit more colloquial, though.

> Das ist doch *derbe* unnötig! Das Wetter ist *derbe* kalt, man. Passiert *derbe* oft, nicht?
>
> *Krass* unnötig. Es ist doch fast nicht zu glauben, wie *krass* gefährlich diese Straßenkreuzung doch tatsächlich ist …
>
> *Voll* bescheuert. *Total* unnötig.

Comment: I'd say "a bit more colloquial" is quite some understatement... :-)